# Shibboleth - how it works?

Tags: authentication, authorization, shibboleth

I try to understand how Shibboleth authentication works. What a user have to supply to authenticate? Is is login and password? If so, is it an only option? How do I create a new login/password for a new user? What if some users already have some logins/passwords within their organisation? Where can I read some 'high-level' tutorial covering practical aspects of using Shibboleth for authentication?

Answer (score 7):

Shibboleth is first of all a framework to build a Single Sign-on (SSO) system using SAML, so you need to quickly Google something about SSO.

Shibboleth is made up of different comonents useful to implement a *whole SSO system*, but usually you have to implement just a part of the system...

To figure *what components* of the system you need and to understand the basic concepts take a look at **Shibbolteh wiki**: 
[Component Interactions](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT), [Understanding Shibboleth](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB/DeploymentBackground) and [How it All Fits Together](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/FlowsAndConfig).

After the basics, you can see really good instructions on configuration and examples [SWITCH Guides](http://www.switch.ch/aai/support/howto/).

Also, Shibboleth provide a useful testing service to test your system: https://www.testshib.org

Comment: Some of the links are broken